# Batch file runs with "not recognized...command", how to fix this?

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I have a batch file which when executed sets PATHs, prompts user for input and loads a script via Python. The python script creates a grid with the size of each cell determined by the user input variable (`cellsize`). The following is from my .bat file:

```
@echo off
rem Root OSGEO4W home dir to the following directory
call "C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\o4w_env.bat"

rem List available o4w programs
rem but only if osgeo4w called without parameters
@echo on

set PYTHONPATH=C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python
set PATH=C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\bin;%PATH%

@echo off
echo.
set /p cellsize="Enter cellsize: "
cellsize=1
cmd /k python "Script.py" %cellsize%
@echo on
```

The .bat works the way it's supposed to, I obtain the correct results, but I receive the following error:

> 'cellsize' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

What simple mistake(s) did I make? I am a beginner but still learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line must read:

> set cellsize=1

but surely this line seems more useful *before* the set /p line as an initialization, since otherwise it cancels the effect of that line.

Comment: That explains why Python was hanging up on me when I tested it with @npocmaka's answer. Brilliant, thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
echo.
set /p cellsize="Enter cellsize: "
set cellsize=1
cmd /k python "Script.py" %cellsize%
@echo on
```

you need `set`

Comment: +1, thank you very much buddy! As @guidot mentioned, I had to switch the line round. Hope I don't offend you if I accept his answer :)

Comment: @Joseph - yes guidot answer is more accureate